# I want to make a https on nginx. How do I use the crt file?

Tags: ssl, nginx, installation, crt

I bought a EssentialSSL certificate on sslcertificate.com.
Then I got these files.

1. AddTrustExternalCARoot.crt
2. COMODORSAAddTrustCA.crt
3. COMODORSADomainValidationSecureServerCA.crt
4. mp_abc_net.crt

Dose anyone know how to setup nginx with the file?

Answer (score 0):

Its worked on my server, FYI.

```
server {

 listen 80;
 listen 443 ssl;
 server_name  portfolio.yaxiong.me;

 ssl on;
 ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/private/pageguy.crt;
 ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/pageguy.key.unsecure;
}
```

Comment: you are a chinese. so I speak chinese then. 你知道怎么样创建key file 吗？

Comment: Its ok, I can speak English,I remeber the time when I download the crt files from sslcertificate.com, it only provide me two file as list above, I dont know why u got four files, but I think the configuration part on nginx wouldnt make too much differences, so thats all I can help so far.

Comment: Theres some command to generate it, I think u get it through google.

Answer (score 0):

There is a nice tutorial in digital ocean blog about setting up SSL in various web server you can check it out. [How To Install an SSL Certificate from a Commercial Certificate Authority](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-an-ssl-certificate-from-a-commercial-certificate-authority)